# how to add two different times in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a function with the following code in it:

```
DECLARE @requestedtime datetime,
    @Timeintervel int,
    @TotalTime datetime 

select @Timeintervel= datepart(MINUTE,l.Timeinterval)  
from Location_tbl l 
where l.LocName=@location

select @requestedtime= t.Paydate 
from Transaction_tbl t 
where t.TBarcode=@cardID
```

I am trying to do this:

```
  select @TotalTime=    DATEADD(MINUTE,@requestedtime,@Timeintervel)
```

...but it returns the following error:

Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Input parameters:

- `@timeintervalue`  15 (15 minutes)
- `@requestedtime` is 2013-05-07 17:55:42.000 I want to add this two times.

I want to get total time=2013-05-07 18:10:42.000

How can I get that? What function do I have to use?

Comment: You could use two functions [DATEPART(MINUTE,...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) and [DATEADD(MINUTE,...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx). See my second solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Note: I have seen you have questions tagged with `SQL Server 2008`.

SQL2008+ has [TIME data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx). In this case, I would use this solution:

```
DECLARE @RequestedTime TIME(0),
        @TimeIntervel TIME(0);

SELECT  @RequestedTime=CONVERT(TIME(0),'2013-07-20 00:25:00'),
        @TimeIntervel=CONVERT(TIME(0),'2013-07-25 10:10:10');

SELECT  @RequestedTime AS [@RequestedTime],
        @TimeIntervel AS [@TimeIntervel];

/*
@RequestedTime   @TimeIntervel
---------------- ----------------
00:25:00.0000000 10:10:10.0000000
*/

SELECT  DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00:00',@RequestedTime) AS ColDiff,
        DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00:00',@RequestedTime),@TimeIntervel) AS ColFinalResult;

/*
ColDiff     ColFinalResult
----------- ----------------
1500        10:35:10.0000000
*/
```

Warning 1: You need a unique index on `Location_tbl` table (key: LocName) otherwise first 
query is non-deterministic (for diff. query executions you might get diff. results) though data is unchanged.

Warning 2: You need a unique index on `Transaction_tbl` table (key: TBarcode) otherwise second query is, also, non-deterministic (for diff. query executions you might get diff. results) though data is unchanged.

**Solution 2:** If you need to add only the minutes to a `time` value/variable.

```
DECLARE @RequestedTime_Minute INT,
        @TimeIntervel TIME(0);

SELECT  @RequestedTime_Minute=DATEPART(MINUTE,'2013-07-20T00:25:00'),
        @TimeIntervel=CONVERT(TIME(0),'2013-07-25 10:10:10');

SELECT  @RequestedTime_Minute AS [@RequestedTime_Minute],
        @TimeIntervel AS [@TimeIntervel];

/*
@RequestedTime_Minute @TimeIntervel
--------------------- ----------------
25                    10:10:10.0000000
*/

SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE,@RequestedTime_Minute,@TimeIntervel) AS ColRequestedResult;

/*
ColRequestedResult
------------------
10:35:10.0000000
*/
```

Comment: I re-writed(edited above) my function what ever you said..while calculating total am getting error Argument data type time is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: Look at the second solution: `@RequestedTime_Minute`'s data type is `INT` not `TIME(0)`.

Comment: i am using your first solution..how i can remove .00000 after 10 seconds

Comment: You have to use `TIME(0)` data type instead of `TIME`(<=>`TIME(7)`, default precision for `TIME` is 7 (100ns)).

Comment: sir,,i made change in my requested date,now my requested date is 2013-05-07 17:55:42.000,,so how i can add minutes to this date

Comment: `DATEADD(MINUTE, NoOfMinutes , RequestedDate)`: `NoOfMinutes`'s data type should me and integer and `RequestedDate`s data type should be `[SMALL]DATE[TIME][2][OFFSET]`. Look in [Book Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following function to add minutes to DATE AND TIME:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, @Timeintervel, @requestedtime)
```

If you have any doubts please go through the following links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx